# Meaning of 'gobbo' / 'gobbi'

Tags: word-meaning, translation, swearwords

The dictionary says 'gobbo' (noun) means a hunchback.

I was watching this video of Mourinho after the Juve game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Z5Qm9CIYHk

A comment underneath says:

> Godo come un porcellone, gobbi del cazzo.

I am assuming "godo come un porcellone" means something like "I'm enjoying this like a pig in the muck", but I'm stuck at "gobbi del cazzo". Is this a cultural reference? (I know what 'cazzo' means :-)

Comment: Hmm.. I am under the impression that he's using *gobbi* as a generic insult. That would be quite uncommon though and I might be missing some context.

Comment: (Incidentally, *porcellone* has almost certainly a sexual connotation, although your understanding of the meaning is broadly correct)

Comment: @DenisNardin I can assure, being a “gobbo”, that it was an insult clearly directed to Juventus supporters.

Comment: @abarisone Indeed I was missing some context :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some parts of Italy *gobbi*, regardless of its literal meaning, is used by supporters of other football teams to derogatorily refer to supporters (and occasionally players) of Juventus.

So, yes, that sentence translates approximately as “I'm enjoying this as a big, fat pig, you fucking Juventus supporters/players”.

An [article in *Il Post*](https://www.ilpost.it/2014/11/24/tifosi-juventus-gobbi/) relates some theories about the origin of this nickname, among which the fact that a jersey Juventus players wore in the 1950s, when they ran, became filled by the air in the upper back, so giving them the appearance of being hunchbacks.